# .Net Core 3 Identity - User in Role not working

Tags: .net-core, identity, roles

Please can anyone advise as I'm struggling with a new .Net Core 3.0 app with ASP Identity and SQL,it is behaving as if the user is not a member of a role when it is.  I have had a look but cannot see any similar posts -  I have initially followed the document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I have created the roles and added a user to the role:

[image: SQL User in Role]

I have ensured that .addroles has been added to ConfigureServices and I have also tried to apply this as a policy in startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

       
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o => {
            o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2);
            o.SlidingExpiration = true;              
        });

        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
   o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3));

        services.AddRazorPages();
                   

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole",
                 policy => policy.RequireRole("System Administrators"));
        });


    }
```

In Configure i have also referenced:

```
app.UseAuthorization();
```

If I look further I can see that the account is indeed registering that it is a member of the role:

*Debug image:*

[image: Debug image]

And by trying the following two attempts in the controller:

```
  [Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdministratorRole")]
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }


  [Authorize (Roles = "System Administrators")]
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I keep receiving the access denied view:

*Denied view:*

[image: Denied View]

I'm out of ideas as to why this is not working, please can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your role 'System Administrators' has a space in it.

Roles cannot have spaces, try 'SystemAdministrator' instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Josh, I have removed the spaces in the role names throughout but sadly this problem is still occurring

Comment: Well, after a restart of VS that has indeed worked! thank you again Josh